# How to filter for a certain JSON response within 3 iterations

Tags: python, arrays, json, loops

```
params = {
    'direction': 'desc',
    'page': '1',
    'sort': 'created_at',
    'perPage': '100'
}

response = requests.get('/ledger', params=params, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)

data = response.json()

payouts = [result['category'] for result in data['results']]
final = [result['debitCents'] for result in data['results']]
status = [result['status'] for result in data['results']] 
date = [result['createdAt'] for result in data['results']]

if status == "requested":
    for (x, y, z) in zip(final, date, status):
        print(f'Payout => {x/100:.2f} | Date => {y}  | Status => {z}')
else:
    pass
```

the JSON had a few possibilities I want to filter through

1. `"status": null`
2. `"status": "requested"`
3. `"status": "success"`

I only want to print the 3 `"requested"` and I have to loop through each part of the JSON and find that. It won't print but the requests work when I remove the if statement. How can I format this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide a sample, but from your code this data structure can be inferred for the received data:

```json
{
  "results": [
    {
      "category": "some category",
      "debitCents": 2,
      "status": null,
      "createdAt": "2022-07-01"
    },
    {
      "category": "some category",
      "debitCents": 3,
      "status": "requested",
      "createdAt": "2022-07-02"
    },
    {
      "category": "some category",
      "debitCents": 4,
      "status": "success",
      "createdAt": "2022-07-03"
    }
  ]
}
```

You are looping over the data 4 times, to extract 4 lists of values (although you don't use the `payouts` / `category`, so I will be ignoring that as well).

However, there's really no need to construct those lists first, and then zip them back together, if all you need is looping through them and using the ones you're interested in (the `"requested"` ones).

Also, you check for the value of `"status"` and then expect the `zip()` to somehow know which tuples to include in the zip and which to ignore, which won't work (how did you expect it to know what to include?)

Here's some code that does what you seem to want to do:

```
# leaving out the first bit, just assuming you got the data and it is structured as above

for result in data['results']:
    if result["status"] == "requested":
        print(f'Payout => {result["debitCents"]/100:.2f} '
              f'| Date => {result["createdAt"]}' 
              f'| Status => {result["status"]}')
```

That's all, nothing else needed. If you expected your code to do anything more, you should focus the question on that specifically (or probably write a new, more focused one).

When writing code, only use commands when you *know* what it is they do, and why they are in the place they are in. If you string along commands that you think 'may help', your code is almost certain to either not work, or have unintended side-effects.

The code I wrote:

- loops over `data['results']`, assuming it's some sequence like a list
- for each `result`, checks if the status is `"requested"`
- and only if that's the case, prints a formatted like of the values of *that* `result`

In general, you should include some sample data with your questions on StackOverflow and provide a really clear explanation of what you're getting and what you expected, if you want a maximally useful answer.

Comment: Wow thanks. I guess I overthought it. I've been making multiple scripts across one websites APIs I use frequently and i've been piecing together old parts from those working projects to try and fix new ones but I should restudy some parts in python because they slip my mine so easily. my thought was a for loop then an if statement

Comment: If I wanted to add all the values would I just do a for loop to append them into an array then add?

Comment: That's one way to do it, another would be to initialise a counting variable to 0 and just add to it as you loop over them - both have advantages, I would recommend picking the one that you find easiest to read and understand, as it makes it easier to come back to the code and build on it (or reuse it)

Comment: Used a list, got it

Comment: You're welcome, if you feel this has answered your question, please click the checkmark, so your question no longer appears as unanswered.